# How to programmatically stop a migration?

Tags: migrations

Say I want to stop a migration that I'd like to stop on preImport under similar circumstances as a dependency not being fulfilled, is there a way to do this?

I would like to stop the migration and prevent postImport from running, preferably from preImport().

```
public function preImport() {
  parent::preImport();
  if($this->externalDependency == 0){
  // Stop the migration, and maybe even throw an error.
  }
}
```

Comment: throw a [`MigrateException`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21migrate%21includes%21exception.inc/class/MigrateException/7) maybe?

Comment: That's a route I guess I'll have to try out. It's strange, because all of migrate has pretty good documentation, but I see no mention of anything anywhere regarding the answer to my question.

Comment: See line 259 of [base.inc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21migrate%21includes%21base.inc/7), I suspect the message level helps to control what action is taken when it's raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MigrateException is the answer (kudos to Clive).
postImport() still runs even after the exception was thrown, so I just have to do the same check on postImport like so.

```
public function preImport() {
  parent::preImport();
  if($this->externalDependency == 0){
  throw new MigrateException('Dependencies were unfulfilled.');
  }
}

public function postImport() {
  parent::postImport();
  if($this->externalDependency == 0){
  return false;
  }
  // My code here
}
```

Comment: FYI it does not work anymore. preImport() call is not wrapped in a try/ctach block in Migrate 2.7
If you still want to interrupt your migration at this moment, you also have to overwrite processImport() and wrap a parent::processImport() call in your own try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

According to my comment on Luke solution, here is the complete code to interrupt you Migration in Migrate these days.

```
public function preImport() {
  parent::preImport();
  if($this->externalDependency == 0){
  throw new MigrateException('Dependencies were unfulfilled.');
  }
}

public function postImport() {
  parent::postImport();
  if($this->externalDependency == 0){
  return false;
  }
  // My code here
}

public function processImport(array $options = array()) {
  try {
    $result = parent::processImport($options);
    return $result;
  }
  catch (MigrateException $e) {
    $this->endProcess();
    drupal_set_message($e->getMessage(), 'error');
    return MigrationBase::RESULT_STOPPED;
  }
}
```